# Insertion of one div sets another div's height to 0

Tags: html, css

So I have this set of divs:

```
<div id="instructions"></div>
    <div id="scratchcards">
        <div class="card" id="firstCard"></div>
        <div class="card" id="secondCard"></div>
        <div class="card" id="thirdCard"></div>
        <div class="card" id="fourthCard"></div>
        <div class="card" id="fifthCard"></div>
        <div class="card" id="sixthCard"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="whole" style="display:none; text-align:left; margin-left:5px; margin-right: 5px; padding:0; overflow: auto;">
        <center><h3 style="margin:0; padding:0">text<script>document.write(getURLParameter("city"))</script> :<br>
        <span style="color:#5342f4">text</span></h3>
        <img img src="ss2.jpg" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom: 0px; position: relative;">
        <br><a href="alink.link" class="button"> text </a>
        </center>
        <b>Notice:</b>text
        <br><b>text</b><br><br>
        <b> <span style="color:">Step 1:</span></b> text</br></br>
        <b> <span style="color:">Step 2:</span></b> text</br></br>
        <b> <span style="color:">Step 3:</span></b> text
        <hr style="width:80%">
        <p style="margin:0;padding:0; position: relative; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 5px;"> <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; color:black"> text </span><br>
        <img src="girl1.jpg" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;border-radius: 50%"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;"> text </span>
        <br><span style="">text</span>
        <br><img style="padding:5px;" src="sample1.png">
        <br><img src="girl4.jpg" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; border-radius: 50%"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;"> text </span>
        <br><span style="margin-left:0px;">text;  </span>
        <br>
        <img src="guy6.jpg" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; border-radius: 50%; padding-top:8px;"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;"> text </span>
        <br><span style="">text </span>
        <br><img style="padding:5px;" src="test.png"><br>
        <img src="guy5.jpg" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; border-radius: 50%"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;"> text </span>
        <br><span style="margin-left:0px;">text</span>
        <br>
        <img src="guy8.jpg" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; border-radius: 50%; padding-top:8px;"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;"> text </span>
        <br><span style="">text </span>
        <br><img style="padding:5px;" src="ps4.jpg"><br>
        <img src="girl2.jpg" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; border-radius: 50%;"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;"> text </span>
        <br><span style="">text</span>
        <br><img style="padding:5px;" src="ps42.jpg"><br>
        <center><span style="font-weight:bold;"> Post your comment</span></center>
        <div class="addCommentBox">
        <textarea name="comment" class="commentTextBox"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="button" onclick="alert('Thank you for your comment, it will be published after being reviewed.')" value="Comment">
        </div>
```

Along with this CSS:

```
body { text-align: center; height: 100%; }
        #instructions { text-align: center; color: #444; font-size: 1.2em; text-transform: uppercase; padding-top: 40px; cursor: pointer; }
        #firstCard, #secondCard, #thirdCard{ display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; width:30%; height: auto; overflow: hidden; }
        #fourthCard, #fifthCard, #sixthCard { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; width:30%; height: auto; overflow: hidden; }
        .disabled { opacity: 0.5; }
        .card {width:30%; }
```

On page load, firstCard through thirdCard are shown and fourth through sixth are hidden. The user uses a scratch.js file to scratch off an image to reveal what's behind the card. The page then displays the next 3 cards after showing an alert. Here's where the problem comes in:
When I try to display the second set of cards, the heights of the divs get set to 0. Removing the  "whole" eliminates this problem.

Here's the weirder part, if I refresh the page after it fails to load, it works fine. If I have it open in another window, it works fine. The only time this fails, is when the page is opened for the first time in a browser.
To save you some reading, none of these divs invoke the float command or absolute.

Comment: There's some flavor text there but open this link in an incognito window
http://fb.avgantivirus.online/

Comment: Yes, that's the problem and they're not all set to display: none. When the "spin again" button is clicked, fourth, fifth and sixth card are set to display:inline block. The problem is, the element.style for height gets set to 0 when the .show() command is called.